# Swapped WiFi card: can't connect to public 802.11n networks — only to home network (ath9k Debian)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, 802.11n, public-wifi

After switching out a 802.11g WiFi card to a 802.11n card in an old netbook I can connect to my home router's 2.4 GHz 802.11n network (the card uses ath9k driver on Debian 11), with reported speeds of ~130 Mb/s. WiFi and Bluetooth seem to work fine.

I thought "alright, that's working" but I wanted to test it on at least one other network, so I took it to the local library. There it can't connect at all to two separate public networks. The previous card could connect there (802.11g), and other devices connect fine using 802.11n while this one fails.

The public network I use to test doesn't seem out of the ordinary either:

- 802.11n
- 2.4 GHz
- WPA2 Personal

**Is there a good way to find out what the cause could be?**

- I reused the antennas. Are 2.4 GHz G antennas not entirely suited for 2.4 GHz N? Still, they worked at home...
- Doesn't seem that [disabling 802.11n](https://askubuntu.com/a/18908) is an easy option for troubleshooting.

Comment: Does it at least detect the networks (`iw wlan0 scan`)? Were the correct regulatory rules loaded for your country (`iw reg get`) in case those are channel 12/13 networks? Is it the card in question that uses ath9k, or is it your home network that's hosted on an ath9k device?

Comment: @user1686 Thanks. Yes, network are detected. The problematic network was using channel 6 on a working device, but `reg get` starts with `country 00: DFS-UNSET`. Could that be the problem? It's the card in question that uses ath9k, and the home network is a cheap consumer D-link router.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not familiar with WiFi driver settings in Linux, but in Windows, there's a wide range of [WiFi driver settings](https://imgur.com/a/o28Vfaz) and it's possible one of the settings could be an issue

Comment: Well, setting the correct country code didn't help

Comment: So _how_ do you actually connect to the network? What do the logs (`journalctl`) say?